# Change in middle name

Tags: visas, usa, passports

I have a valid US visa on my old passport which is still valid for next 3 months. I have applied and acquired a new passport with same first name (Ambreen) and Surname (Alwani, that is my maiden name) as that of my old passport but previously my father name was written on my old passport and now on my new passport (after marriage) father name is replaced by my husband's name.

So do I have to apply for new US visa again because of change in my father to husband name while my name and surname remains same i-e Ambreen Alwani.

Please suggest what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

From the Official website:

> **I changed my name. Is my U.S. visa with my old name still valid?**
>
> If your name has legally changed through marriage, divorce, or a court
>   ordered name change, you will need to obtain a new passport.  Once you
>   have a new passport, the **Department of State recommends that you apply
>   for a new U.S. visa to make it easier for you to travel** to and from
>   the United States.

https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/frequently-asked-questions/about-basics.html

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. The OP hasn't changed her name, and beside, this is a _recommendation_ by the Department of State, not a requirement.

Comment: Change in middle name is still a name change.

Comment: And a recommendation is still not a requirement. It just says it will make your life easier, not that it is required.